# arm - how to check endianness of an object file

Tags: windows, arm, objdump, object-files

Using `objdump`, how do you check if an `.obj` is little- or big-endian?

Comment: you must clearly mention about the environment where your building. Windows is not mentioned in the question. Are you building arm on your windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you run `objdump -d <filename>`, you should see at the top of the disassembled code a line that is in this format:

```
<filename>: file format (string that contains littlearm or bigarm)
```

I assume that littlearm implies little endian and bigarm implies big endian.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is to use the [file](http://www.linfo.org/file_command.html) command that will give you the result what you expect.

```
$file your_object_file.obj
example output
$firmware.img: Linux jffs2 filesystem data little endian
```

Comment: Add that in your question you want this to do in Windows.